# unbound breakpoint when debugging ionic project in vs code?

Tags: angular, debugging, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have a little ionic project in visual studio code. When I wanted to debug it, the breakpoints turned pale with the message "Unbound breakpoint" when I hover over them.

However, in a normal angular application, I have no trouble debugging.

Ionic is installed globally.

I have checked existing solutions but they didnt work so far. In my angular.json I set `sourceMaps` to `true`, but nothing changed.

This is my launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8100",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "sourceMaps": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks for every help!

Comment: Your config works within my Ionic 5 app. If you put a break-point within app.component.ts does it work? If you're trying to put a break-point within a lazy loaded module, it will only activate once that module been loaded into memory. You could also try running the app with `ng serve` to help identify the cause of the issue.

Comment: @JohnTiggernaught no it doesnt work....but I could make it work differently. when creating the ionic app via the ionic cli, I used `type=angular` and this time it worked....also I changed `pwa-chrome` to `chrome` in my launch.json